# Javascript in Node.js using functions with different signatures

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, parameters, overloading

What's the difference between `query(userOptions)` and `query(...args)` ? I get that they are probably overloads for the same function call, but I'm not sure how they would be actually called or under what circumstances in a calling program to select which overload is used, especially with the `static` decoration.

```
class Gamedig {
    constructor() {
        this.queryRunner = new QueryRunner();
    }

    async query(userOptions) {
        return await this.queryRunner.run(userOptions);
    }

    static getInstance() {
        if (!singleton) singleton = new Gamedig();
        return singleton;
    }
    static async query(...args) {
        return await Gamedig.getInstance().query(...args);
    }
}
```

Comment: MDN is a great reference source, for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) means that the function is assigned to the constructor, i.e. `Gamedig`. The function is called as

```
Gamedig.query(...)
```

Without `static` the function is accessible on an instance if `Gamedig`, i.e.

```
var instance = new Gamedig();
instance.query(...);
```

JavaScript doesn't support function overloading.

---

`userOptions` vs `...args` has nothing to do with that. The [*rest parameter*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in a function definition means that the function accepts a variable number of arguments and they are all collected in an array which is assigned to that parameter (`args` in your example).

Example:

```js
function foo(...bar) {
  console.log(bar);
}

foo(1);
foo(1,2);
foo(1,2,3);
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks if it was a banal question. This particular program is from a library that's meant to be called from an included command-line version or as a library into a larger application. Maybe that's the reason for the 2 query functions.

Comment: I suspect people not deep in ES6 classes will be confused by "static means that the function is assigned to the constructor". I presume you're referring to the fact that you can call the static method via `instance.constructor.query(...)` as well as via `Gamedig.query(...)`.